# What is the general strategy for handling multiple missing shared objects?

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm, shared-libraries

I'm still learning Linux, so bear with me...

I ran ldd on Apache's httpd and found many missing shared libraries. I am new to this machine and am not sure whether some of these are misplaced or actually missing. My best guess is someone installed a newer version of httpd and it requires newer versions of the shared libraries it cannot find. I was able to find some of these libraries in other locations on the machine by doing "locate libmm", for instance. However, I don't know what version to link it with.

Case in point: What should the following link to?

`libssl.so.2 => not found`

I have found no libssl.so.2 on my machine but I have found...

```
/lib/.libssl.so.0.9.8e.hmac
/lib/.libssl.so.6.hmac
/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8e
/lib/libssl.so.6
/lib64/.libssl.so.0.9.8e.hmac
/lib64/.libssl.so.6.hmac
/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
/lib64/libssl.so.6
/usr/lib/libssl3.so
/usr/lib64/libssl3.so
```

If I don't have the file to link to, then how can I find the correct package online to install it? For instance, if I use `yum search mm`, it is difficult to figure out what package to install, and which one contains the correct shared library.

Is an easier way to simply reinstall Apache?

Here is the output of ldd.

```
$ ldd ../bin/httpd

libaprutil-1.so.0 => .../apache/2.2.24.rhas5.x86_64/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00002ae571b0c000)
libapr-1.so.0 => .../apache/2.2.24.rhas5.x86_64/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00002ae571d2f000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x0000003fd7c00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ae571f68000)
libmm.so.14 => not found
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00002ae572183000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003fd8000000)
libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x0000003fd7000000)
libcurl.so.4 => not found
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00002ae5724c2000)
libldap-2.4.so.2 => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003fd8800000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002ae5726f4000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003fd8400000)
libexpat.so.1 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003fd6c00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003fd6800000)
libmm.so.14 => not found
libcurl.so.4 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libexpat.so.1 => not found
libmm.so.14 => not found
libcurl.so.4 => not found
libexpat.so.1 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install this from a package? I would just do a `yum install httpd`, and it should take care of dependencies.

if you really want to go track down some of this stuff, you could try [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net), and search there for provides/requires stuff. But it would take a lot of time.